# How to show format date: dd/MM/yyyy 10:05 pm

Tags: date, format, angular5

I'm using the date pipe to format my date, but I just can't get the exact format I want to show dd/MM/yyyy hour PM/AM

Comment: if the answer help you solve problem, you can mark as accepted, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use date pipe `this.datePipe.transform(new Date() ,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm a');`
If you want to display lower case you can add pipe `lowercase`

```
{{ today | lowercase }}
```

More format at https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepipe-in-component-test-2